# Using Visual Studio Package Manager Console for other solution

Tags: .net, visual-studio, powershell, nuget

My source code is composed of **many solutions**. In order to collect information on the installed packages (version, license, etc.) of each solution, I'm looking for a way to organize it automatically.
As I know so far there is an option to use the `Get-Package` [command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/ps-reference/ps-ref-get-package) via the Visual Studio Package Manager Console, or to use the `dotnet list package` [command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-list-package)

The problem:

`Get-Package` - Seems to be available only from a specific solution and only for this specific solution. Since I have many solutions it's not a trivial solution

`dotnet list package` - It gets a solution as a parameter so I can run it on every solution, bu it works only for the new `csproj` files, but I have many old `csproj` files

The preferred way for me is to use the Powershell command available in the console since I have the option to get the license URL from it by using this command:

`Get-Package | Select-Object Id, Version, LicenseUrl, ProjectName`

Is there a way to run the above command in one solution for all a given list of other solutions (assuming I can get easily the **solutions list**) or it requires to run only from a specific solution each time?

Comment: Did you try the command like this: dotnet list "solution path" package

Comment: @JingmiaoXu-MSFT Yep. As I wrote it covers only the new `csproj` style, but I have many projects with the old style `csproj`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use`dotnet list package` to get packages from your solution which includes old and new `csproj`, you can migrate from packages.config to PackageReference. Please refer to doc:[Migrate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference).

But there are some Limitations: Migration is not currently available for C++ and ASP.NET projects.

**Notice:** **You'd better make backup before migration to prevent unexpected effects of upgrades**

If you want to use `Get-Package` to get packages for other solutions, you can add Parameter `ListAvailable` to list packages available from a package source. Suppose the packages you download in your multiple solutions are from nuget.org, you can set nuget.org as package source. It will return all packages in multiple solutions from specified source.

For example

```
Get-Package  -ListAvailable | Select-Object Id, Version, ProjectName,LicenseUrl
```

RESULT

[image: RESULT]

**UPDATE**

if you  want to collect information on the installed packages (version, license, etc.) of each solution, i suggest to write ps script to achieve it automatically.Below are script example .I test it and it can get packages list for all a given list of other solutions.

```
# solution root path
$SOLUTIONROOT = "C:\Users\Administrator\source\"
# solutions list(assuming i can get easily the solutions list)
$SOLUTIONlIST = "JsonDemo","Nuget-exe"
for($i =0 ;$i -lt $SOLUTIONlIST.Length;++$i){
   $path = Join-Path $SOLUTIONROOT $SOLUTIONlIST[$i]
   $FileName = Join-Path $path "packages.Config"
   cd $path
   # old project uses Get-package new project uses dotnet list
  if (Test-Path $FileName ){
    ListAllPackages $path
   } else {
    dotnet list  package
   }
   cd $SOLUTIONROOT
  }
  
# get old style csproj package lists
Function ListAllPackages ($BaseDirectory)
{
    Write-Host "Starting Package List"
    $PACKAGECONFIGS = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force $BaseDirectory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
        Where-Object { ($_.PSIsContainer -eq $false) -and  ( $_.Name -eq "packages.config")}
    ForEach($PACKAGECONFIG in $PACKAGECONFIGS)
        {
            $path = $PACKAGECONFIG.FullName
            $xml = [xml]$packages = Get-Content $path
                            foreach($package in $packages.packages.package)
                            {
                                 Write-Host $package.id,$package.Version
                             }

        }
}
```

RESULT
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response! Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me from one solution on another solution. Regarding migration, due to organizational reasons, I can't migrate. Generally, I have many solutions and I'm looking for a way I can automate the process of collecting their dependencies + licenses

Comment: Hi, Are all your packages in your multi solutions from different sources such as public feed or local feed ?

Comment: They are all from nuget.com

Comment: If it doesn't work for you ,i suggest you check your package source and make sure it's configured correctly. Also, you can navigate to your [global package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders) path(Windows: %userprofile%\.nuget\packages),packages are installed to here. You can use command `dir ` to get list of pacakges you've installed.

Comment: Hi, have you tried above workaround and does it work for you?

Comment: Hi, Thanks! I've rechecked but got the same results. The workaround is interesting but if I use the global package approach, I will get the list of all nugets from all existing solutions, but I need the packages of a list of solutions (I've modified my question to reflect it more).

Comment: From MS doc[Get-Package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/ps-reference/ps-ref-get-package),I'm afraid there is no supported parameters to retrieve the packages of a list of solutions.

Comment: I'm afraid too :( 
Thanks for your try!

Comment: @Roni I found a workaround to get packages list for other solutions with PS script .Updated the answer. Hope it can help you.